# Javascript não pega link clicado com a mesma ID

Tags: javascript, link, área-de-transferência, button

Eu estou colocando um script para copiar o link para área de transferência, usando o plugin `ZeroClipboard`. O problema é que eu tenho uma lista com vários links que vem do `MySQL`. E no loop da lista vem sempre a `id` "copy-link" no `<a>`. Quando eu clico no segundo link ou nos próximos, então ele não copia para a área de transferência, ele só está copiando o primeiro. Creio que o problema seja a ID por ser a mesma.

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // main.js
            var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-link") );

            client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
              // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

              client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
                // `this` === `client`
                // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
                alert('Link copiado!');
              } );
            } );
        </script>
```

**html**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="copy-link" data-clipboard-text="AQUI VAI O LINK">Copiar Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tens várias âncoras todas com a mesma ID então `document.getElementById("copy-link")` só vai retornar um elemento e nõ vai funcionar nos outros...

A maneira correta é trocar esses ID por class. Mas fazendo isso ou não podes ainda ir buscar esses elementos via atributo `data-clipboard-text`.

De qualquer maneira como são mais que um precisas de um ciclo for para correr o plugin em cada elementto. Sugestão:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-clipboard-text]');
[].forEach.call(links, function (el) {
    var client = new ZeroClipboard(el);
    client.on("ready", function (readyEvent) {
        // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

        client.on("aftercopy", function (event) {
            // `this` === `client`
            // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
            alert('Link copiado!');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta utilizar o `click` event em vez do `ready`, assim esta acção é accionada cada vez que ocorre um click num link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // main.js
    var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-link") );

    client.on( "click", function() {
    // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

        client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
            // `this` === `client`
            // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
            alert('Link copiado!');
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Não resolveu, só copia o primeiro link.